# the **Cayley table** of the group given by the following **Cayley diagram**

Tags: cayley-graphs

How to write the the **Cayley table** of the group given by the following **Cayley diagram** ?

[image]

**Answr:**

From the diagram I understand that the group contains $ \ 10 \ $ elements and the group is generated by **two elements** .

The group should be $ \{<a,b> | a^2=1, b^5=1 \} \ $

The elements should be $ \ \{e,b,b^2,b^3,b^4,a,ab,ab^2,ab^3,ab^4 \}  \ $ .

**But what should be the multiplication rule between the elements ?**

I actually am unable to write the table ?

**Can anyone help me with the Cayley table ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is $D_{10}$, the dihedral group of order $10$.

The presentation is $\langle a,b \mid a^2=b^5=1, (ab)^2=1 \rangle$.

Note that your presentation would be infinite.

The Cayley table:

$$\begin{array}{l|l}
\cdot & e & b & b^2 & b^3 & b^4 & a & ab & ab^2 & ab^3 & ab^4 \\\hline
e & e & b & b^2 & b^3 & b^4 & a & ab & ab^2 & ab^3 & ab^4 \\\hline
b & b & b^2 & b^3 & b^4 & e & ab^4 & a & ab & ab^2 & ab^3 \\\hline
b^2 & b^2 & b^3 & b^4 & e & b & ab^3 & ab^4 & a & ab & ab^2 \\\hline
b^3 & b^3 & b^4 & e & b & b^2 & ab^2 & ab^3 & ab^4 & a & ab \\\hline
b^4 & b^4 & e & b & b^2 & b^3 & ab & ab^2 & ab^3 & ab^4 & a \\\hline
a & a & ab & ab^2 & ab^3 & ab^4 & e & b & b^2 & b^3 & b^4 \\\hline
ab & ab & ab^2 & ab^3 & ab^4 & a & b^4 & e & b & b^2 & b^3 \\\hline
ab^2 & ab^2 & ab^3 & ab^4 & a & ab & b^3 & b^4 & e & b & b^2 \\\hline
ab^3 & ab^3 & ab^4 & a & ab & ab^2 & b^2 & b^3 & b^4 & e & b \\\hline
ab^4 & ab^4 & a & ab & ab^2 & ab^3 & b & b^2 & b^3 & b^4 & e
\end{array}$$